# can a loop solve and occurrence of excessive if statements?

Tags: vba

I want to format a shape (Oval 1) using cell value "A1" I want to format the next shape (Oval 2) using cell value "A2" and so on.. I can get this done with repeated "If", "Else if" statements but I'm looking for a way to achieve this with a "for" loop or some other method to reduce the if/else statements and make the code simpler yet still effective.

```
Sub format_connector()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 1")).Select

If Range("D5") = "GREEN" Then
    Call green
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "YELLOW" Then
        Call yellow
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "BLACK" Then
        Call black
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "BLACK/WHITE" Then
        Call black_white
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "RED" Then
        Call red
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "RED/WHITE" Then
        Call red_white
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "ORANGE" Then
        Call orange
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "ORANGE/WHITE" Then
        Call orange_white
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "BLUE" Then
        Call blue
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "BLUE/WHITE" Then
        Call blue_white
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "BROWN" Then
        Call brown
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "BROWN/WHITE" Then
        Call brown_white
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "VIOLET" Then
        Call violet
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "GRAY" Then
        Call gray
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "WHITE" Then
        Call white
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "WHITE/BLACK" Then
        Call white_black
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "WHITE/BLUE" Then
        Call white_blue
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "WHITE/BROWN" Then
        Call white_brown
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "408-4001-882" Then
        Call cavity_plug
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "408-4001-445" Then
        Call cavity_plug
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "408-4002-073" Then
        Call cavity_plug
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "408-4001-935" Then
        Call cavity_plug
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "BLANK" Then
        Call blank
End If
```

Comment: `For i = 1 to 100` or something like that, `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval " & i)`... and `Range("A" & i)`...

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code. Try [edit]ing it in.

Comment: I'm calling macros within the code which brings me to another question about whether I can call "macro1" using a variable like "A" ex. "call macro A"

Comment: Much better! I'd recommend mapping a `Scripting.Dictionary` with the D5 values as keys and the macro names as values - then you just verify if the value of D5 is mapped, and if it is, you `Application.Run` the associated macro name.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Since every condition uses the same left operand in a comparison, the `If...Else If...End If` block could be expressed with a `Select...Case...End Select` block, and that would already reduce some of the repetition.

```vb
Private Function GetMacroName(ByVal source As Range) As String
    Select Case Range("D5")
        Case "YELLOW":
            GetMacroName = "yellow"
        Case "BLACK":
            GetMacroName = "black"
        Case "BLACK/WHITE"
            GetMacroName = "black_white"
        '...
        Case Else
            GetMacroName = "blank"
    End Select
End Function
```

And then you can use `Application.Run` to invoke the parameterless procedure:

```vb
Application.Run GetMacroName(Range("D5"))
```

You can use a loop to run this instruction for different ranges:

```vb
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet '<~ sure of that?

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To N '<~ N=number of iterations; presumably the number of oval shapes
    Dim oval As Shape

    On Error Resume Next '<~ manually handle non-existing shape #i
    Set oval = sheet.Shapes("Oval " & i)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not oval Is Nothing Then
        Application.Run GetMacroName(sheet.Range("D" & 5 + i - 1)), oval
    End If

    Set oval = Nothing
Next
```

Alternatively we could iterate the sheet's `Shapes` collection:

```vb
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet '<~ sure of that?

Dim oval As Shape, i As Long
For Each oval In sheet.Shapes
    i = i + 1
    If Left(oval.Name, 4) = "Oval" Then
        Application.Run GetMacroName(sheet.Range("D" & 5 + i)), oval
    End If
Next
```

Note that in both cases, the macro receives the `Shape` object it works with. By passing parameters, you make your code less reliant on global state, and easier to follow: you shouldn't have to work out who's the caller 3 frames up the call stack that called `.Select` on some shape, to know what you're working with! Passing parameters makes things much simpler to debug later.

```vb
Public Sub Yellow(ByVal sh As Shape)
    sh.ForeColor = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Note that if that's all that's going on here, you should only have one macro instead:

```vb
Public Sub FormatOvalShape(ByVal oval As Shape, ByVal color As Long)
    oval.ForeColor = color
    '...
End Sub
```

..and let the caller parameterize the call - you'll reduce code duplication even further. Actually, it would remove the need to map macro names; instead we map color codes:

```vb
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet '<~ sure of that?

Dim oval As Shape, i As Long
For Each oval In sheet.Shapes
    If Left(oval.Name, 4) = "Oval" Then
        FormatOvalShape oval, GetColorCode(sheet.Range("D" & 5 + i))
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: This all makes sense now but can I run a macro that formats "oval 1" with data from cell "D5" and format "oval 2" with data from cell "D6" and so on..

Comment: You will need to pass parameters to your procedures, I think. Or have one map for D5 and another for D6.

Comment: "oval 1" corresponds to cell "D5" and "oval 2" corresponds with cell "D6" and so on all the way up to "oval 47"..

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
Sub format_connector()
    ' 008 26 Apr 2020

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim SubName As String
    Dim R As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet                        ' Be safe! Call the sheet by name.
    On Error Resume Next
    Ws.Unprotect
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    R = 5                                       ' start the loop at D5
    Do
        SubName = Replace(Ws.Cells(R, "D").Value, "/", "_")
        If SubName = "" Then Exit Do
        R = R + 1

        i = i + 1
        Ws.Shapes("Oval " & i).Select
        If Val(SubName) Then SubName = "cavity_plug"
        Application.Run SubName
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code was modified to select Ovals 1, 2 etc. for as many as there are parameters specified in column D, starting from D5.

Comment: This code worked but it only formatted "Oval 1"... based on the "D5" value. No other shapes were formatted.

Comment: I want "Oval 2" to be formatted by cell "D6" value, "Oval 3" to be formatted by cell "D7" value..

Comment: If *Oval 1* is linked to D5 and *Oval 2* to D6, how many ovals are there? This is a minor change but I suspect that all the subs you call are, in fact, a single sub by nature which should be called with different parameter, one of them being the shape itself. Can you post a sample?

Comment: Sub FormatConnector()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Call underscore 'converts to underscore between colors

Dim color As String

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 1")).Select
color = Range("D5").Value
Call CAVITY_PLUG
End If
Application.Run color

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 2")).Select

color = Range("D6").Value
Application.Run color

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 3")).Select

color = Range("D7").Value
Application.Run color

Comment: I apologize for asking you for more code. There is no room to deal with it in this thread. The only question we can deal with here is how many ovals there are. You mention D5:D7. Is that all? Or is there a dynamic end, like "as many ovals as there are values in column D"?

Comment: There is a dynamic end. There are as many ovals as there are values in column D...

Comment: OK. I've modified the code to work in a loop as you describe.

Comment: I'm glad we finally got it to work the way you want. Now let's clean up. Please delete your first comment because it no longer applies. You may also like to delete your own answer for the same reason. Select this answer as a guide to others if it's the answer you selected.

Answer (score 0):

Sub FormatConnector()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Call underscore 'converts to underscore between colors

Dim color As String

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 1")).Select
color = Range("D5").Value
Call CAVITY_PLUG
End If
Application.Run color

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 2")).Select

color = Range("D6").Value
Application.Run color

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 3")).Select

color = Range("D7").Value
Application.Run color

Comment: This is the most efficient way I've come up with so far to edit shape format using a sub procedure called by range.value..